# How to access application and options with SwiftUI openUrl

Tags: swiftui, spotify

I'm trying to integrate Shopify SDK on a SwiftUI project and I'm having some troubles with the authentication flow.

The code provided on the documentation is pretty straight forward:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        spotifyConnection.sessionManager.application(application, open: url, options: options)
        return true
    }
```

with SwiftUI though this delegate method is never called so I'm trying to use openUrl

```
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MenuView()
            .onOpenURL { (url) in
                spotifyConnection.sessionManager.application(??, open: url, options: ??)
            }
        }
    }
```

Question is how do I access the parameters application and options from here?

Comment: I don't know anything about Shopify, but given the func works, you can call the function by `.onAppear` attached to `MenuView`

Answer (score 1):

I am also having the same issue, for Spotify SDK particularly, I tried passing in `UIApplication.shared` and an empty options dictionary, which seems to work. I also tried examining the `options` dictionary when I use a UIKit AppDelegate lifecycle. It shows it's returning `openInPlace` to be false in the options dictionary in the Spotify url callback.

Answer (score 0):

You need an [UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiapplicationdelegateadaptor)

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: MyAppDelegate

    var body: some Scene { ... }
}

class MyAppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        spotifyConnection.sessionManager.application(application, open: url, options: options)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately this function is never called when the app is loaded from callback url. Might have something to do with using Scene.